# Let $M$ a cyclic $R$-module of order $\alpha$. If $\beta\mid\alpha$ then there is a unique submodule of order $\beta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ a principal ideal domain and $M$ a cyclic $R$-module of order $\alpha$. Show that for each divisor $\beta$ of $\alpha$ there is a unique submodule of order $\beta$.

*Note: below $\langle\cdot\rangle$ stay for ideal generator and $\langle\!\langle\cdot\rangle\!\rangle$ stay for (sub)module generator.*

My work so far:

By the uniqueness of the cyclic decomposition on primary submodules of a torsion module it is enough to see the case when $\alpha=p^n$ for some prime $p$.

I already know that $\tau: \langle\!\langle v\rangle\!\rangle\to R/\langle p^n\rangle,\, rv\mapsto r+\langle p^n\rangle$ is a $R$-module isomorphism and so it is enough to check that the submodules $\langle\!\langle p^{n-j}+\langle p^n\rangle\rangle\!\rangle$ are the unique submodules of order $p^j$ in $R/\langle p^n\rangle$.

If $x\in R$ induces a submodule of order $p^j$ in $R/\langle p^n\rangle$ then it is clear that $x=r p^{n-j}$ for some $r\in R$, and so $x\le p^{n-j}$ as induced submodules with equality when $r$ is a unit.

However I get stuck trying to show that $r$ must be necessarily an unit. Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ is aunit *modulo* $p^n$, or, what's equivalent $r$ is coprime to $p$. If it were not, we  would have $r=p^k r'$, where $\gcd(r',p)=1$, therefore $\;x=r'p^{n-j+k}$ would have order $p^{j-k}\ne p^j$ if $\ne 0$.

Comment: if $r$ is coprime to $p$ then, how it can be a unit? I dont follow what you mean by $r$ is a unit modulo $p^n$, how can $r$ be invertible there? I mean, how it is possible that $[p^{n-j}]\in\langle\!\langle rp^{n-j}+\langle p^n\rangle\rangle\!\rangle$?

Comment: That's because of *Bézout's identity: there exist integers $u,v$ such that $ur+vp^n=1$ so that $ur\equiv 1\mod p^n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The isomorphism theorem on $M \cong R/\langle \alpha \rangle$ gives a correspondence between submodules of $M$ and submodules of $R$ that contain $\langle \alpha \rangle$.